# JAGS: posterior predictive distribution

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, bugs, gibbs, jags

I am fitting a simple linear regression model with R & JAGS:

```
model {
    for (i in 1:length(ri)){
        ri[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i],tau)
        mu[i] <- alpha + b.vr*vr[i] + b.ir*ir[i]
    }

    #posterior predictive distribution
    for (j in 1:length(pvr)){
        pmu[j] <- alpha + b.vr*pvr[j] + b.ir*pir[j]
        pri[j] ~ dnorm(pmu[j],tau)
     }  

    #priors for regression
    alpha ~ dnorm(0,0.01)
    b.vr ~ dunif(-10,0)
    b.ir ~ dunif(0,10)

    #prior for precision
    tau ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
    sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
}
```

I am trying to calculate the posterior predictive distribution with new data (`pvr` and `pir` in the model). But somehow the reported results (`pri`) do not make sense (the means of `pri` are smaller than expected).

Could someone explain me, is something wrong with the model specification?

Comment: could you at a minimum provide the input data that you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*disclaimer* I still don't fully understand your model; but without at least a reproducible example, this is the best I can offer. It is not clear exactly what you are doing here. For example, how are `pvr` and `pir` calculated? Would it make sense to calculate them inside the same model?

**Answer**

I am assuming that your data includes observations for `mu[]` but not `pmu[]` and you want to estimate `pmu[j]` given `j` values of `pvr` and `pir`.

Append the `pir` and `pvr` to the `ir` and `vr` columns, get rid of the second for loop, and then consider the values of `mu[]` estimated using `pir` and `pvr` to be the posterior predictive estimates of `mu`. Then replace the two `for` loops with this:

```
for (i in 1:length(ri)+length(pri)){
    ri[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i],tau)
    mu[i] <- alpha + b.vr*vr[i] + b.ir*ir[i]
}
```

I have done something similar, but without predicted regressors, similar to the example given by [Gelman et al in 'Bayesian Data Analysis' (pp 598-599](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/bugsR/software.pdf) starting under *posterior predictive simulations*).

Comment: @David pvr and pri are user supplied data: they are the predicted regressors...

Comment: @teucer are they predicted from user-supplied values of `ir` and `vr`? if so, how? and if so, why not calculate `pri` and `pvr` yourself inside the JAGS model?

Comment: @teucer, this is a shot in the dark since I still don't understand your model, and this might be the same as what you already have, but would it make sense to append the `pir` and `pvr` to the `ir` and `vr` columns, get rid of the second `for` loop, and then consider the values of `mu[]` estimated using `pir` and `pvr` to be the posterior predictive estimates of mu?

Comment: @David I want to have some credible interval for the predictions (`pri`), this is why having `mu` is not enough. If I append `pvr` and `pir` I would get `alpha`, `b.vr` and `b.ir` for the whole `ri`, right? Or can I have `ri` with missing values e.g. (1,2,3,NA,NA) and append the regressors?

Comment: @teucer yes, you can have ri with missing values; this is a neat feature of bugs that simplifies calculation of a predictive interval.

Comment: @David could please edit your answer accordingly so that I can accept?As I said earlier having only the mean is not enough for my purposes, I would like to have the other statistics...

Comment: @teucer I have updated my answer, I will be interested to know if it works.

Comment: @David Thx! Actually the both approaches work as outlined in [link](http://www.stanford.edu/group/mapss/colloquium/papers/hierarchicalJackman.pdf) (page 39, second paragraph). Your solution is obviously more eficient...